# Simple neural network debugging

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm trying to create a python neural network implementation based on [coding train course](https://github.com/CodingTrain/Toy-Neural-Network-JS) but I'm stuck on debugging and can't find out what did I mess up. Currently an issue occurs while calculating the deltas for hidden layer, I assume there are some issues with matrices operations which influent next steps. Can anybody help with debugging?

```
import numpy as np


class NeuralNetwork:

    def sigmoid(self, x):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

    def sigmoid_d(self, x):
        return x * (1 - x)

    def __init__(self, input_nodes, hidden_nodes, output_nodes):
        # Save size properties
        self.input_nodes_count = input_nodes
        self.hidden_nodes_count = hidden_nodes
        self.output_nodes_count = output_nodes

        # Generate random weights
        self.weights_ih = np.random.random((self.hidden_nodes_count, self.input_nodes_count))
        self.weights_ho = np.random.random((self.output_nodes_count, self.hidden_nodes_count))

        # Generate weights for biases
        self.bias_h = np.random.randn()
        self.bias_o = np.random.randn()

        # Set learning rate
        self.learningRate = 0.1

    def calc_hidden(self, inputs):
        # Prepare hidden values
        hidden_without_bias = np.dot(self.weights_ih, inputs)

        # Add bias for hidden values
        hidden_not_activated = np.add(hidden_without_bias, self.bias_h)

        # Execute hidden activation
        hidden = list(map(lambda x: self.sigmoid(x), hidden_not_activated))

        return hidden

    def calc_output(self, inputs):
        # Prepare output values
        output_without_bias = np.dot(self.weights_ho, inputs)

        # Add bias for output values
        output_not_activated = np.add(output_without_bias, self.bias_o)

        # Execute output activation
        outputs = list(map(lambda x: self.sigmoid(x), output_not_activated))

        return outputs

    def predict(self, inputs):
        # Calc hidden values
        hidden = self.calc_hidden(inputs)

        # Calc output values
        outputs = self.calc_output(hidden)

        return outputs

    def train(self, inputs, targets):
        # Calc hidden values
        hidden = self.calc_hidden(inputs)

        # Calc output values
        outputs = self.calc_output(hidden)

        # Calc output errors
        output_errors = np.subtract(outputs, targets)

        # Calc the output gradient
        gradients = list(map(lambda x: self.sigmoid_d(x), outputs))
        gradients = np.multiply(gradients, output_errors)
        gradients = np.multiply(gradients, self.learningRate)

        # Calc deltas
        hidden_t = np.transpose(hidden)
        weights_ho_deltas = np.dot(gradients, hidden_t)

        # Adjust output weights by deltas
        for i in range(len(self.weights_ho)):
            for j in range(len(self.weights_ho[i])):
                self.weights_ho[i][j] += weights_ho_deltas[i][j]
        self.bias_o += gradients

        # Calc the hidden layer errors
        weights_ho_t = np.transpose(self.weights_ho)
        hidden_errors = np.dot(weights_ho_t, output_errors)
        # Calc the hidden gradient
        hidden_gradients = list(map(lambda x: self.sigmoid_d(x), hidden))
        hidden_gradients = np.multiply(hidden_gradients, hidden_errors)
        hidden_gradients = np.multiply(hidden_gradients, self.learningRate)

        # Calc hidden deltas
        inputs_t = np.transpose(inputs)
        weights_ih_deltas = np.dot(hidden_gradients, inputs_t)

        # Adjust hidden weights by deltas
        for i in range(len(self.weights_ih)):
            for j in range(len(self.weights_ih)):
                self.weights_ih[i][j] += weights_ih_deltas[i][j]
        self.bias_h += hidden_gradients


if __name__ == '__main__':
    neuralNetwork = NeuralNetwork(2, 2, 1)

    training_data = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
    training_output = [[0], [1], [1], [0]]

    for i in range(1):
        index = np.random.randint(0, len(training_output))
        neuralNetwork.train(training_data[index], training_output[index])

    print(neuralNetwork.predict([1, 1]))
```

Comment: But what part are you stuck at? What is the error, what is the expected output, etc?

Comment: Actually it's difficult to precise which part is invalid. I believe it's an issue with calculating the deltas and adjusting the weights. 
On the subject of expected output, the training dataset after running more times should learn XOR function so I'd like the predict for [1, 1] to be as close as possible to 0.
I know that I didn't clear the problem out as I should but at this moment I'm a bit lost in the subject as I spent lots of time trying to debug it

Comment: You should post the full error trace that you are getting, and also the steps that you took to try and debug yourself.

Comment: Currently there is an error during producing a dot product of hidden layer and gradient (and this error is clear) but I think the main issue is the algorithm and I believe that for someone familiar with the subject this error can be gross. I tried to find out where is the difference between my implementation and actual algorithm but failed. Sorry for being not precise enough